# Javascript function called more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used jquery in my project. I need to insert few rows in between two rows using jquery. It seemed tricky to me so i used the hide() and show() function to show the rows when clicked. however, The need is that on 1st click it shows extra rows and on second click the extra rows should hide.

For that I have written a javascript function like this:

```
activityDetailTableExpand: function (aData, ref) {
    var indexOfClick = ref.parentElement.rowIndex;
    console.log(indexOfClick);
    if (aData[6] > 1) {
        if (!$("#activityDetailTable").find("tbody tr").eq(indexOfClick + 1).is(":visible")) {
            for (var j = 0; j < aData[6]; j++) {
                $("#activityDetailTable").find("tbody tr").eq(indexOfClick + j).show();
            }
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < aData[6]; j++) {
                $("#activityDetailTable").find("tbody tr").eq(indexOfClick + j).hide();
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(aData);
},
```

here the parameter aData will have the contents of the row that is shown in the table. ref will have the exact element which was clicked. 
Now this logic is working fine for one table row while the other this code is executed twice. The control comes back from jquery.js file to my file. As such once shown table rows are again hidden after the second execution. i am not sure what is wrong in this.

EDIT:

This is the code that binds the click to my function:

```
    bindClick : function(tableId,tableName,dialogId){
            if(tableId=='approvals-table'){
                $("#"+tableId+" tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
                    var aData = tableName.fnGetData(this);
                    var functionMap={
                            'approvals-table': function(){com.impetus.isas.getDeviceForApprove(aData);},
                        };
                    functionMap[tableId].call(this);
                    com.impetus.isas.openDetailDialog(dialogId);
                      }).css({
                          'cursor' : 'pointer'
                      });
            }else{
                $("#"+tableId+" tbody tr").find('td:gt(0)').on("click", function(event){
                    var aData = tableName.fnGetData(jQuery(this).parent('tr')[0]);
                    var functionMap={
                            'users-table': function(){com.impetus.isas.getUserDetail(aData[0]);},
                            'devices-table': function(){com.impetus.isas.getDeviceDetail(aData[0]);},
                            'approvals-table': function(){com.impetus.isas.getDeviceForApprove(aData);},
                            'activityDetailTable': function(){com.impetus.isas.activityDetailTableExpand(aData, this);},
                        };
                    functionMap[tableId].call(this);
                    com.impetus.isas.openDetailDialog(dialogId);
                      }).css({
                          'cursor' : 'pointer'
                      });
            }
        },
```

In my case the one of the activityDetailTable is called

Comment: Sounds like you bound the click event twice.

Comment: Well that was my first thought and spent hours trying to find out. turns out its isn't so. Because it is this very code that handles both the clicks. On one table row its working fine (The last row of the column) however its not working for table rows that are in between.

Comment: that isn't possible. jquery isn't magically triggering this event twice when you click once. it's getting handled twice, which can only happen if you bind to it twice (or you click it twice.) show the code you are using to bind this event. (and the code that executes that code)

Comment: What executes bindClick?

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT. Added the bindClick function I used

Comment: I want to see what executes that function.

Comment: bindClick function executes this function. The bindClick is used to bind Click event of particular table with a particular function. The mapping is done in the functionMap

Comment: No, what executes bindClick.